ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_sysconfigdata_x86_64_conda_cos7_linux_gnu'
I am using python==3.8.5 here, just running the code gives me this error.
 File "run_inference_text_out.py", line 18, in <module>
    import albumentations as A
  File "/home/test/miniconda/envs/anydoor/lib/python3.8/site-packages/albumentations/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .augmentations import *
  File "/home/test/miniconda/envs/anydoor/lib/python3.8/site-packages/albumentations/augmentations/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .blur.functional import *
  File "/home/test/miniconda/envs/anydoor/lib/python3.8/site-packages/albumentations/augmentations/blur/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .functional import *
  File "/home/test/miniconda/envs/anydoor/lib/python3.8/site-packages/albumentations/augmentations/blur/functional.py", line 9, in <module>
    from albumentations.augmentations.geometric.functional import scale
  File "/home/test/miniconda/envs/anydoor/lib/python3.8/site-packages/albumentations/augmentations/geometric/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .functional import *
  File "/home/test/miniconda/envs/anydoor/lib/python3.8/site-packages/albumentations/augmentations/geometric/functional.py", line 6, in <module>
    import skimage.transform
  File "/home/test/miniconda/envs/anydoor/lib/python3.8/site-packages/skimage/transform/__init__.py", line 38, in <module>
    from .radon_transform import (radon, iradon, iradon_sart,
  File "/home/test/miniconda/envs/anydoor/lib/python3.8/site-packages/skimage/transform/radon_transform.py", line 6, in <module>
    from ._warps import warp
  File "/home/test/miniconda/envs/anydoor/lib/python3.8/site-packages/skimage/transform/_warps.py", line 7, in <module>
    from ..measure import block_reduce
  File "/home/test/miniconda/envs/anydoor/lib/python3.8/site-packages/skimage/measure/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from ._polygon import approximate_polygon, subdivide_polygon
  File "/home/test/miniconda/envs/anydoor/lib/python3.8/site-packages/skimage/measure/_polygon.py", line 2, in <module>
    from scipy import signal
  File "/home/test/miniconda/envs/anydoor/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/__init__.py", line 211, in __getattr__
    return _importlib.import_module(f'scipy.{name}')
  File "/home/test/miniconda/envs/anydoor/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/home/test/miniconda/envs/anydoor/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/signal/__init__.py", line 331, in <module>
    from ._peak_finding import *
  File "/home/test/miniconda/envs/anydoor/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/signal/_peak_finding.py", line 8, in <module>
    from scipy.stats import scoreatpercentile
  File "/home/test/miniconda/envs/anydoor/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/stats/__init__.py", line 467, in <module>
    from ._stats_py import *
  File "/home/test/miniconda/envs/anydoor/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/stats/_stats_py.py", line 55, in <module>
    from ._resampling import _batch_generator
  File "/home/test/miniconda/envs/anydoor/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/stats/_resampling.py", line 10, in <module>
    from ._axis_nan_policy import _broadcast_concatenate, _broadcast_arrays
  File "/home/test/miniconda/envs/anydoor/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/stats/_axis_nan_policy.py", line 11, in <module>
    from scipy._lib._docscrape import FunctionDoc, Parameter
  File "/home/test/miniconda/envs/anydoor/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/_lib/_docscrape.py", line 8, in <module>
    import pydoc
  File "/home/test/miniconda/envs/anydoor/lib/python3.8/pydoc.py", line 366, in <module>
    class Doc:
  File "/home/test/miniconda/envs/anydoor/lib/python3.8/pydoc.py", line 396, in Doc
    def getdocloc(self, object, basedir=sysconfig.get_path('stdlib')):
  File "/home/test/miniconda/envs/anydoor/lib/python3.8/sysconfig.py", line 521, in get_path
    return get_paths(scheme, vars, expand)[name]
  File "/home/test/miniconda/envs/anydoor/lib/python3.8/sysconfig.py", line 511, in get_paths
    return _expand_vars(scheme, vars)
  File "/home/test/miniconda/envs/anydoor/lib/python3.8/sysconfig.py", line 172, in _expand_vars
    _extend_dict(vars, get_config_vars())
  File "/home/test/miniconda/envs/anydoor/lib/python3.8/sysconfig.py", line 559, in get_config_vars
    _init_posix(_CONFIG_VARS)
  File "/home/test/miniconda/envs/anydoor/lib/python3.8/sysconfig.py", line 430, in _init_posix
    _temp = __import__(name, globals(), locals(), ['build_time_vars'], 0)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_sysconfigdata_x86_64_conda_cos7_linux_gnu'

I have tried activating and deactivating the environment. I also tried creating a new environment. But it didn't work.
